# dynamic attribute value contain space C#

Tags: c#

I am creating anchor tag dynamically and adding attributes in C#. adding data attributes like below

```
anchor.Attributes.Add("data-name", "[Sales][Experience About]");
```

what happened in UI it created like

```
<a data-name="[Sales][Experience" About] href=""></a>
```

**because of spacing in attribute value ,the quotes closed in Experinece itself so it creating some problem for us.**

how we can supply attriibute value with spaces in C#. we have so many attributes value we need to display like as like same value in UI too.

how to reslove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` to encode the attribute value:

```
anchor.Attributes.Add("data-name", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("[Sales][Experience About]"));
```

Which will result in

```
<a data-name="[Sales][Experience%20About]" href=""></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . but it  returning like  "%5bQuestionnaire%5d.%5bQuestionnaire%5d.%5bCategory%5d.%26%5bOFSP%5d%26%5bOverall+Sales+Experience%5d"  for this string  [Questionnaire].[Questionnaire].[Category].&[OFSP]&[Overall Sales Experience]